# Best way to store location data - Android

Tags: android, gps, sharedpreferences, storage

I'm developing a geofencing program and I need to save the user's path.

Up to now I stored a Set of Strings in SharedPreferences and each X min the data will be sent to the server and clear all variables, so I don't think there will be storage problems.

I was wondering if there is a best way to do this.

UPDATE:
As long as SharedPreferences does not suport List I will follow the aproach of @chiastic-security and I will make a class Point that will have the points in float type and timestamp, then I will add it to a Set.

This is a sample of my code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ArrayList<String> path;


public void updatePath(Points point){
        path.add(point);
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(path); 
        prefs.edit().putStringSet("path", mySet).commit();
    }
```

And Points class

```
 public class Points {
            private Double[] coordinates;
            private long timestamp;

            public Points(Double[] coordinates ){
                this.coordinates = coordinates;
                this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long Shared Preferences only allow us to use `int`, `boolean`, `String` and `Set<String>`, I ended up using [ComplexReferences](https://github.com/fsilvestremorais/android-complex-preferences).

It allows us to use every data structure we want to use.

In my case, I used an Array of Objects `Point` because we need to complet a buffer before to send the information.

```
ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(this, "mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Points[] path = new Points[N_POINTS];

void addObj(){
    complexPreferences.putObject("path", path);
    complexPreferences.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing the path, you should be storing the `List` rather than the `Set`, otherwise you'll lose the ordering. It'll be a jumble of points rather than something you can trace over time.

It's impossible to say much more because we don't know what is in a `point`, but `String` seems like an odd choice. I'd expect a custom class that stores latitude and longitude and possibly altitude (`double`). It might also store a timestamp (`long`), and if so, then a `Set` will then be OK because you can recover the ordering (though a `List` would still be more natural).

You'll need to make sure the class implements `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1):

If are more than one preferences, may be could be better use sqlite to store and retrieve the locations.
This is a simple example of how you can store data on sqlite. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

I hope it works for you

Comment: This could be a very go aproach in case to need to store for a long period of time but in this case we are trying to store information for a determined period of time. Thanks anyway!